# Sed is is very confused about the file path I am giving it

Tags: bash, shell, sed, zsh

I am trying to pass a file with sed substitutions to sed, and it ignoring parts of the path I give it:

First, let's start with a simple assertion:

```
 test -f workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed && echo "exists"
exists
```

Yup, file exists.
Now, the problem:

```
sed -E -n -f  /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv  
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

It's dropping everything before the `o` in `workdir`!

I have tried a fresh shell, with no extensions

```
env -i /opt/brew/bin/bash
bash-5.2$ sed -n -E -f "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed"  "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

I have tried an older version of bash:

```bash
env -i bash
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$ sed -n -E -f "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed"  "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv"
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

I have tried it with `zsh`

```bash
env -i zsh
sed -E -n -f /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv                                                                                                                                                   
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried `gsed`

```bash
gsed -n -E -f "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed"  "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv" 
gsed: couldn't open file orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

I cd directly into the file of the file and remove all pathing:

```bash
bash-5.2$  cd $(dirname "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed" )     
bash-5.2$ pwd
/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58
bash-5.2$ ls templates.sed
templates.sed
bash-5.2$ ls -al templates.sed
-rw-r--r--  1 cbongior  staff  62087 Aug  7 15:51 templates.sed
bash-5.2$ sed -E -n -f templates.sed /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
bash-5.2$ chmod 777 templates.sed 
bash-5.2$ sed -E -n -f templates.sed /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

Using substitution:

```bash
bash-5.2$ set -x
bash-5.2$ sed -E -n -f $PWD/templates.sed $PWD/data.psv   
+ sed -E -n -f /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

tried this:

```
bash-3.2$ cd $(dirname  /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed)
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58
bash-3.2$ ls -al templates.sed data.psv
-rw-r--r--  1 cbongior  staff  1081134967 Aug  4 13:30 data.psv
-rwxrwxrwx  1 cbongior  staff       62087 Aug  7 15:51 templates.sed
bash-3.2$ sed -E -n -f templates.sed data.psv 
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

Ok, now it's just making things UP!

```bash
bash-3.2$ cd ../../..
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/cbongior/dev/omc
bash-3.2$ sed -E -n -f orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ sed -E -n -f workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ sed -E -n -f Workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ sed -E -n -f WWorkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv
sed: WWorkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ sed -E -n -f \workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv  
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

So, if I add the missing `w` it ignores that. But if I add 2 `w`'s it doesn't?

Here I changed up the arg order:

```
 sed -E -n -f workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

Ok, last attempt: If this is a shell issue, then any tool with have the same confusion:

```
bash-5.2$ grep -E '.*'  /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed | wc -l
+ grep -E '.*' /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed
+ wc -l
     499
```

My current guess is that `(g)sed` is interpreting this as some kind of switch, but I don't see it anywhere in the docs and this is code from a script that's been working for a while.

Comment: you can also try using the full path to the sed, for example : `/usr/bin/sed -E -n -f "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed" "/Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/data.psv"`

Comment: This is strange. For debugging, I would do a `cd /Users/cbongior/dev` and use relative pathes for _sed_. Do you get the same effect? If so, the error must be in the commands stored in `templates.sed`.

Comment: Have you tried `cat file.sed | sed -f - file`?

Comment: @user1934428 - already tried that. See above.

Comment: @Freeman - already tried that, see above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this isn't a problem with the command at all, but with something in the `templates.sed` file. Specifically, I suspect there's a line like

```
workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed
```

...which `sed` will interpret as the `w` command (write the pattern space to a file), with the filename "orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed". Here's a quick demo:

```
$ cat demo.sed 
workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed
$ sed -f demo.sed 
sed: orkdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed: No such file or directory
```

Try running `grep orkdir /Users/cbongior/dev/omc/workdir/2023-08-03/2023-07-21-01-30-19_2023-07-31-23-59-58/templates.sed` and see what it shows.

Comment: `templates.sed` in OP is 62K but, yeah, let's see it.   I just played around with `w` in a `-f` file and when there is a forward slash (implying path) GNU sed will give the error OP mentions when trying gsed:  'couldn't open file'.   If there is no forward slash or if the directory exists, sed will create the file to write to.

Comment: You were dead right! That was the trick. Very first line in my .sed file had this path. It's a bug on my end to fix, but now I know. What a wild red-herring

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the issue you are facing is related to the fact that the `sed` command on `macOS` is different from the `sed` command on `Linux`. The `-i` option on macOS requires an extension argument for backup files, while on Linux it does not. This means that when using the `-i` option on macOS, you need to provide an extension for your backups, like this: `sed -i'.original' -e 's/old_link/new_link/g' *`. This will create backup files with the `.original` extension.

If you want to avoid creating backup files, you can try using another command to achieve the same result. e.g. use  `perl` :

`perl -i -pe's/old_link/new_link/g'` .

Comment: The OP isn't using `-i`.